# Why is the calculation result different between sassmeister and local environment?

Tags: javascript, css, math, sass, gulp

I do complicated calculations.
For example, the following mixin returns **0.00000096** for [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) (used in compiler dart-sass v1.18.0).

But with [gulp-dart-sass](https://github.com/mattdsteele/gulp-dart-sass) this gives different results (**9.6000002259**) on Windows 10. Why is this? I want it to work like SassMeister.

**Sass file**

```
$x: 0.98;
$a: 300;

@function f($x){
  $x: 1 - $x;
  @return 1 - $x * $x * $x * $x * $x;
}

@error f($x) * -$a + $a;
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-dart-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "g",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-dart-sass": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

**SassMeister result**

```
0.00000096
  ╷
9 │ @error f($x) * -$a + $a;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 9:1  root stylesheet on line 9 at column 1
```

**console result**

```
$ npm run gulp sass
[xx:xx:xx] Using gulpfile ~\gulpfile.js
[xx:xx:xx] Starting 'sass'...

Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    style.scss
Error: 9.6000002259
  ╷
9 │ @error f($x) * -$a + $a;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  style.scss 9:1  root stylesheet

[xx:xx:xx] Finished 'sass' after 151 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure, that they are off by 10^7? The small difference i can understand (is probably unavoidable), but the 10^7 is very weird. Maybe you meant `9.6000002259e-7`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte On my console, it was 9.6000002259 and there was no exponent. The console result is also added.

Comment: Which engine did you pick on sassmeister? By default, it uses libsass.